# How to call class instances stored in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, class, instance

I'm using Python 2.7.6 in Kubuntu 14.04; trying (for my own edification) to implement Conway's Life using a single class instantiated for each cell to do the "cellular automaton" work.  In the process, I'm storing an instance in each member of a list of lists.  The problem is, when I try to call instance methods while I iterate through the indices for the list(s), I get an error: `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`.  Here's the code I have:

```
# Conway's Life in Python -- initially with text graphics, 50x50, possibly
# with actual windowing system graphics in a later version.  Use a class
# replicated in quantity (2500!) for each cell to vastly simplify computation;

# is below worth it or not?  Would bring all four cores into computation.
# learn how to do threading to let the cells calculate in parallel, but pass
# signals to keep them in step.

class Cell(object):

  def __init__(self, coords, size):
    # coords is a tuple of x, y; size is the field height/width in cells
    self.position = coords
    self.is_live = False
    pass

  def count_neighbors(self):
    x,y = self.position
    self.neighbors = 0
    for i in range (-1, 1):
      for j in range (-1, 1):
    # add size and modulo (size - 1) to create wrapped edges
    if field[(x + i + self.xy) % (self.xy - 1)] [(y + j + 
                                  self.xy) % (self.xy - 1)]:
      ++self.neighbors
    pass

  def live_or_die (self):
    if self.neighbors < 2 or self.neighbors > 3:
      self.is_live = False
    elif self.neighbors == 3:
      self.is_live = True
    else:
      pass

# main program

extent = 4 #size of field

# create list of lists of Cell objects w/ coord tuples
# for i in range extent:
#   for j in range extent:
#     field[i[j]] = (i,j)

field = [[Cell((i, j), extent) for j in range(extent)] for i in range(extent)]

# insert population setting here

# insert population setting here

for i in range (extent):
  for j in range (extent):
    field[i[j]].count_neighbors()

for i in range (extent):
  for j in range (extent):
    field[i[j]].live_or_die()
```

The last two `for` loops will be wrapped in a `while` for continued operation once I've worked out how to create the initial population and stop the program in a controlled way.  Obviously, `extent` will be set higher once I've got the iteration debugged (50x50 only used about 5.5 MiB RAM prior to adding variables to the methods in `Cell`, so I should be able to run this at screen size with single pixels in graphics mode, if that won't be too slow -- a couple steps per second is plenty fast for my tastes).

Problem is, I'm not seeing a way to individually call the instances of `Cell` stored in `field`.  I *think* the problem here is how I'm nesting the lists, but they have to be nested, don't they?  The `j` lists are members of the `i` list.

Full tracebacK:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyLife.py", line 51, in <module>
    field[i[j]].count_neighbors()
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Can you show us the complete traceback.

Comment: Added full traceback.  I made a change in `count_neighbors` variable ranging while pasting in the code, and now I'm getting a different error; I'm going to change that back to what I had before.

Comment: Okay, I found the problem (I think): where I'm indexing `field [i[j]]`, I should be doing it as `field [i][j]` -- at least, doing that eliminates the error message and the program completes.  Now to find out if the logic is working correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the traceback is your syntax for accessing the nested list elements. It should be:

```
field[i][j].count_neighbors()
```

if you want to access elements from nested lists

Comment: Confusing -- I have to nest the brackets in the list comp to originally create the list of lists, but I can't nest them when I reference the contents?  Python would be giving me gray hair, if it weren't already going gray...

Comment: @ZeissIkon, bot _i_ and _j_ are indexes, when you  write _i[j]_, you try to take element No _j_ of _i_ - which, being integer, it does not have. Want to keep your hair? Don't use one-letter identifiers

Comment: for short-cycling `for` loops, single-letter identifiers are easier.  These loops will ever only be what you see here (except for logic testing/debugging `print` statements), and I've used `i` and `j` consistently throughout the program for this.  I wouldn't consider using single letter variable names for anything else.